# php find characters in url

Tags: php, url, joomla, get

I want to use php to search the current url for `com_agora` and if it finds it to display something and if it doesn't to display something else

the problem is there can be lots of characters after `com_agora` in the url

an example would be this  `com_agora&task=cat_view&gid=41&Itemid=`

so how would I tell it find it while not caring what characters come after a?

Comment: What you're showing there is not an URL, but a query string. Can you show a full string looks like that you want to parse? There may be a clean solution using PHP's URL parsing functions but it's not clear yet what it needs to be doing

Comment: @Pekka: That could also be a URI path. But it looks quite a lot like a query. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // or taken from another source //
if( strpos($uri, 'com_agora') !== false ){
   // Your action goes here! //
}
```

If you need more complex parameters operations please use `parse_str`.

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming you are talking about the query string here (the part after the `?`)

For a bullet-proof approach, use [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/parse_str) to take apart the query string and to see whether there is a parameter named `com_agora`. This has the advantage that it will ignore the occurrence of the search term anywhere else in the string (e.g. in another parameter value).

```
$query_string = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]; // e.g. com_agora&task=cat_view
$query_string_parsed = array();       

parse_str($query_string, $query_string_parsed); 

// Search for "com_agora"
$found = array_key_exists("com_agora", $query_string_parsed);
```

Comment: Pekka like a boss +1. This is the authoritative answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(strpos($url, 'com_agora') !== FALSE) { /* do something */ }
```

Comment: This will also return true if `com_agora` is a part of another variable or value

Comment: @pekka: the op only asked if com_agora is in the string, he does not care about anything else in the string. at least that's how i read the question

Comment: I think this is a case of the OP not asking the right question :) At least it looks that way from the example he gives

Comment: @pekka: probably, but as it stands now it's a valid answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Joomla has a class that allows you to work with URL `JURI`, you can [learn more about `JURI` class on Joomla's documentation site](http://docs.joomla.org/JURI).

Here is fully functional code, that will do what you what it to do

```
<?php

// Sample URL
$url = "http://www.mysite.com/index.php?option=com_agora&task=cat_view&gid=41&Itemid=5";

// Using JFactory::getURI() without parameter will give you URI of current webpage
$uri = JFactory::getURI($url);

// Here is the structure of the object
//
//object(JURI)[136]
//  public '_uri' => string 'http://www.mysite.com/index.php?option=com_agora&task=cat_view&gid=41&Itemid=5' (length=78)
//  public '_scheme' => string 'http' (length=4)
//  public '_host' => string 'www.mysite.com' (length=14)
//  public '_port' => null
//  public '_user' => null
//  public '_pass' => null
//  public '_path' => string '/index.php' (length=10)
//  public '_query' => string 'option=com_agora&task=cat_view&gid=41&Itemid=5' (length=46)
//  public '_fragment' => null
//  public '_vars' => 
//    array
//      'option' => string 'com_agora' (length=9)
//      'task' => string 'cat_view' (length=8)
//      'gid' => string '41' (length=2)
//      'Itemid' => string '5' (length=1)

// Get and output option parameter from the URI
echo 'Option = ' . $uri->getVar('option');
//  output = com_agora

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are in Joomla simply do this:

```
$option = JRequest::getVar('option','','GET');
```

The $option variable will then hold the value of whatever is in the URL and you can then go:

```
if ($option == 'com_agora') {
  //Do something
}
```